# how to apply top inner shadow to the body using css

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am a beginner at front-end web development and I am stuck with a problem. I want to apply inner shadow on the top of the window like tinder:- [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v2qs.png)

So how can I implement that with only using HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I applied shadow on **div** only, you can also apply on **body** as well by simply select **body** instead of **div** element in css.

```css
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(230, 205, 108);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 32px 14px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>

<!-- You can use image as well, background color is only use for demonstration  -->

</div>
```